# c++ print out arrays incrementally

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying to print out arrays incrementally like this;

```
TractMultBox->Text = rows[0] + newline;
TractMultBox->Text += rows[1] + rows[0] + newline;
TractMultBox->Text += rows[2] + rows[1] + rows[0] + newline;
```

which would give an output like this

```
3
43
543
```

I can do fine with this code, however. It would like to use a for loop, that would make it easier, since I would like it to output all arrays until max is reached automatically.

Comment: You may find nesting a for loop in another for loop will be helpful here

Comment: Wouldn't your code give an output like `3 343 343543`?

Comment: FYI: Since you're new to SO when you find an answer you like toss them an upvote, when you find the best answer accept it with the check so others know your question has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a for loop indeed perhaps something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int rows[3] = {3, 4, 5};
    for (int i(0); i < 3; ++i)
    {
       for (int j(i); j >= 0; --j)
          std::cout << rows[j];
       std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

If rows contained 345 this would give you the following output:

```
3
43
543
```

Not sure if that's what you wanted but you can adjust the loops accordingly. The key is to have 2 for loops.

**Edit:** Changed to self contained example you can play with

Comment: Was just an example ... I prefer C# over CLI if I'm going the .NET route myself.

Comment: C language seems to be a mess in all the different standards like C#, but CLI/C++ seems to be easier for a noob like me, for now. Thanks again.

Comment: @Tok Doom: That statement would probably make the C# language cry. Each language has it's own standard and it's own strengths. Over time you'll find syntax isn't an obstacle and you'll end up using whatever is best for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want to concatenate and not sum.

```
string text;
for (int i = 0; i < rows.count; ++i)
{
   text = rows[i] + text;
   TractMultBox->Text = text + newline;
}
```

for less lines of code.

```
string text = newline;
for (int i = 0; i < rows.count; ++i)
{
   TractMultBox->Text = (text = rows[i] + text);
}
```

but that's a little hard to read.

Comment: This is way faster than having two loops.

Comment: Amazing the second one is legitimate syntax.

Comment: It was a typo. Sorry. My compiler is my grammar checker.

Answer (score 1):

What about a double loop like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxNRows; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    {
        TractMultBox->Text += rows[j];
    }
    TractMultBox->Text += newline;
}
```

Comment: Yes he will need 2 for loops but I don't believe he wants a sum of values based on desired output shown.

Comment: My bad, edited to update sums for printing in format given in question.